# Laravel! How to compare a collection value with a <input> text?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to compare a collection items values with a  text in my blade template when the user clicks on a button.

Something like this

```
@foreach notes as note

@if $note->number == <input id="number" name="number">

<h2>$note->contente</h2>

@endif

@endforeach
```

Please how can I perform this kind of comparaison?

Comment: This has to be done with Javascript, Blade outputs the HTML way before your Javascript loads

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done with Javascript, Blade outputs the HTML way before your Javascript loads or input change

Here's an example (not to copy paste)

```html
@foreach($notes as $note)

<h2 hidden>{{ $note->name }}</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>

@endforeach
<button onclick="showCorrectNames()">Check</button>
<script>
    function showCorrectNames() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (let input of inputs) {
            if (input.value === input.previousElementSibling.innerText) {
                input.previousElementSibling.hidden = false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### Explanation:

- Always mark the heading to be hidden by default
- Place an input next to it and query its value when the button is clicked
- Listen to the click event on the button and execute a Javascript function
- Get the full list of all input elements
- Iterate through the HTML collection
- If the input value matches the previous heading value (inner text) in the DOM
- Set the hidden attribute of the heading to false

#### Live Example:

```js
function showCorrectNames() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (let input of inputs) {
            if (input.value === input.previousElementSibling.innerText) {
                input.previousElementSibling.hidden = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<h2 hidden>Cecelia Denesik Jr.</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>


<h2 hidden>Cristian McCullough</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>


<h2 hidden>Forest Pollich</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>


<h2 hidden>Mckenna Jacobson</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>


<h2 hidden>Rudolph Luettgen MD</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>


<h2 hidden>Mazie Shields III</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>


<h2 hidden>Mr. Arlo Hudson Sr.</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>


<h2 hidden>Joanie Rogahn</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>


<h2 hidden>Stephan Feil</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>


<h2 hidden>Isadore Schultz</h2>
<input id="number" name="number"><br>

<button onclick="showCorrectNames()">Check</button>
```

I hope this helps